How to set duckdb threads to 1 from default 16
I am trying to set the threads use by DuckDB.
Doing SET threads TO 1; or PRAGMA threads=1; set number of threads to 1, but it somehow increases afterwards.
To recreate:
>>> import duckdb # line 1
>>> duckdb.execute("SET threads TO 1;") # line 2
<duckdb.duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection object at 0x7fb537744630>
>>> duckdb.execute("SELECT 1;").df() # line 3
   1
0  1
>>> q = "SELECT * FROM duckdb_settings() WHERE name = 'threads';"
>>> duckdb.sql(q).df()
      name value                                      description input_type   scope
0  threads     1  The number of total threads used by the system.     BIGINT  GLOBAL

After line 1 number of threads is 16.
After line 2 number of threads is changed to 1.
After execution of the line marked as line 3 the number of threads is becoming 16 again(checking in htop).

I don't see same as you, I executed 'duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM duckdb_settings() WHERE name like '%threa%';").df()'  BEFORE and AFTER each command. this is against duckdb v1.0.0 1f98600c2c

Yes. When I am checking from duckdb_settings(), the number of threads are set to 1 after I explicitly set it. However if you check from OS level(using something like htop), it is showing 16 threads.

when you actually attach to a db instance yes, they will , because until you actually connect to an instance those settings have no bearing on the duckdb engine. set the number of threads to 1 (or whatever) after you connect, then take a look at the number of threads. NB: you need to be monitoring the python process running not some other duckdb instance (just saying)
